# Javascript - Div hide/show - Safari issues

Tags: javascript

I have the following script which works great in Chrome but not in Safari.

In Safari, I get the following error: **SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.**

```js
const btnList = document.querySelectorAll("a[id^=category]");
btnList.forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = this.id.replace('SeeMore', '')
    document.querySelectorAll('.' + id).forEach(el=>el.style.display = 'block')
  });
});
```

```css
.category36, .category37 {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: Skyblue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F9F2D6;
  border-right: 1px solid #F9F2D6;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#" id="category36SeeMore">See more</a>
</p>

<div class="category36">
  test
</div>

<div class="category36" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>

<div class="category36" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>

<div class="category36" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>

<hr>

<p>
  <a href="#" id="category37SeeMore">See more</a>
</p>

<div class="category37">
  test
</div>

<div class="category37" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>

<div class="category37" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>

<div class="category37" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: `"a[id^=category"` --> `"a[id^=category]"`. Chrome is too tolerant, it should point this out too.

Comment: @JeremyThille Please feel free to post as an Answer and I will accept. Thanks for spotting.